# fopen() works properly in a debug session, but doesn't work when I call the file through the browser

Tags: php, fopen, file-access

I'm new to PHP and just faced the problem with creating and opening a file with fopen(). Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $new_file = fopen('file.txt', 'w') or die("Cannot create a file");

    $text = <<<_END
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
_END;

    fwrite($new_file, $text) or die('Cannot write to the file');

    fclose($new_file);
```

When I try to run the file by opening it in the browser I see the next message: 'Cannot create a file'. But when I start debug session everithing works as it supposed to. I suspect that there is some issue with permissions and XDebug uses root access unlike the usual interpreter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem first of all I was needed to check PHP user with the next command:

```
<?php echo `whoami`; ?>
```

It outputs:

```
www-data
```

This is the default PHP user. Next I checked the owner of the folder with this command:

```
ls -dl /var/www/html/test
```

It outputs:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 username username 4096 Jun 26 12:49
```

Next I've sat permissions to the PHP user by running:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html/test
```

Checking once again if the owner changed

```
ls -dl /var/www/html/test
```

And now it outputs

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data username 4096 Jun 26 12:55
```

Done. Now I'm able to create and write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

to write and read permission

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/dicrctoy 
chmod -R 775 /var/www/dicrctoy
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my local environment no error was found
if you're using mac you should check the file permission
use **chmod** command to change permission

What is the meaning of chmod 777?
readable, writable and executable
Setting 777 permissions to a file or directory means that it will be readable, writable and executable by all users